# I'm looking a javascript library that has a tile/grid map data structure

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, game, game-development, data-structure

I'm trying to create grid-based maps for my game. Here's an example of what they will look like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The playable character will always be centered around the viewport and there are times, just like in these pictures, where the map is larger than its viewport. You move by clicking on tiles that you are not on.

The part I'm struggling with is finding a javascript library that has a **decent API** for working with tilemaps/grids.

Here are some requirements:

1. There is going to be metadata in the tiles (e.g., this tile has a bed, this tile has stairs, etc.). I need to be able to retrieve this from the library. It might also be necessary to add/remove/modify metadata at runtime.
2. I *want* the library API to have a "viewport" concept where I could say `giveMeViewPort(3, 5, {2,2})`, and that would return a 3x5 portion of the map around origin (2, 2). This feature would be really nice, but it isn't strictly necessary: if I can do the first thing, I can use it to achieve this.
3. The library should be able to tell me how many rows and columns the map has. Maps will always be a rectangle shape.
4. I'd like to be able to represent edges like in the 2nd and 3rd picture (the dashes).